# compile SQLite amalgamation for Windows Mobile device

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sqlite, compact-framework, compilation

How can I compile the SQLite amalgamation for Windows Mobile device?

Then I want to use in a console to run some commands.

I've created an empty VS project in C/C++ for Smart Device, then included the existing files into Sources and Headers.

When I try to compile I get:
`Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol wmain referenced in function mainWCRTStartup corelibc.lib sqlite3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amalgamation file does **not** contain a `main` function because it's really just the sqlite library, and not a command-line interface program.

You will have to implement the commands yourself and link against the sqlite library.

Answer (score 0):

The [wmain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299386%28VS.60%29.aspx) function is a program execution entry function, means is defined by an application, but not a library.

You most likely have crated a project for *Application* but SQLite is a library, so it does not define (w)main function. So, you should select project type of *Static Library* or `Dynamic-Linked Library`.

You'd be better to refer to the MSDN documentation about creating and setting projects for Windows Mobile applications and decide [which project type to choose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hty7fz7f.aspx)

[Smart Device Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could build the SQLite Amalgamation as a library and link against it...  But if you're writing a native C++ application it's **much** easier to just compile SQLite directly into your project.

First, follow the project wizard settings and create a "Windows Application" and choose "Emply Project".  Choose No ATL, no MFC and no Precompiled-Headers.

Once you have the empty/skeleton project building successfully, add `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` from the SQLite Amalagamation to the project.

In the .CPP file that contains `wmain()` add `#include "sqlite3.h"`

Finally,  in your `wmain()` function, somewhere *after* the initialization code but *before* the main message loop add the following:

```
sqlite3 *db;
sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```

This is the bare-minimum necessary code to create an empty in-memory SQLite database.

If the above project compiles and links - you should be good to go!